# read function C seems to work different on different shells

Tags: c

I have a question: I am working on a Windows laptop from home on `getnextline`, I've been debugging on my Windows Git bash for a while but it turns out when I use my wsl ubuntu shell the output is perfect: `exploding_head`. I believe it is regarding the `read()` function: with Windows bash compiling it seems to read a duplicate of the last byte it read some lines (consistently). Anyone knows why?

My get next line code is in here: https://github.com/Rikkopanda/Codam.git

```
char *create_list(int fd, t_list **list)
{
    int bytesread;
    char *buff_str;
    t_list *new_node;
    t_list *last_node;

    buff_str = calloc(sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE);
    last_node = *list;
    while (find_newline(last_node))  //go to last of list and find
    {
        bytesread = read(fd, buff_str, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (!bytesread)
            break;  //free&return
        //if(last_node)
            
        //printf("\tbuff size |%d|, %s", BUFFER_SIZE, buff_str);
        write(1, &buff_str, BUFFER_SIZE);
        new_node = ft_lstnew_strdup(buff_str);  //malloc lstbuffer & lst
        //printf("hmm =  \n%s\n", buff_str);
        if (!new_node)
            break;  //free&return
        ft_lstadd_back(list, new_node);  //add to back if there is list, else make *lst = new
        last_node = ft_lstlast(*list);
    }
    return (buff_str);
}
```

The output of `write(1, &buff_str, BUFFER_SIZE);` is different on the different OS platforms.

Comment: Please note that `if(!bytesread)` will only catch end-of-file. It will not catch errors. You should also check for errors from `write`, and `calloc`. I also recommend you stop using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like `1`. Use the POSIX standard `STDOUT_FILENO` symbol instead.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and you will see a warning for this

Answer (score 2):

The problem is what you write with

```
write(1, &buff_str, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

You pass a pointer ***to the pointer***, so the function will read from totally wrong location in memory and write whatever it can find there.

You should pass plain `buff_str`.

---

Also note that `read` might read *less* than requested. You should only write `bytesread` bytes to the standard output.

Furthermore, `read` does *not* "null terminate" the data it reads. If it reads exactly `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes, there will be no null-terminator and you can't use `buff_str` as a string. Read at most `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` bytes instead, to make sure that the data is terminated. Or allocate `BUFFER_SIZE + 1` bytes.